# How can bare Git repository be ahead of my working repository?

Tags: git, git-push, git-bare

I made a bare repository clone of my Git working repository.  The remote bare repo is located on network drive and I have been pushing to it so I have backup on different physical media.  I am now getting an error on an attempt to push to the bare repository because my local repository is **behind** the remote repository.  All modifications to the remote repository have been by pushing from my working repository.  How could my local repo be behind the remote when there have been no other changes made to the remote repo? 
Here is the error I am getting when trying to push to remote repo

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags --set-upstream AlcatrazVehicleBW1 BitworksDevelopment:BitworksDevelopment FixSetOsDateTime:FixSetOsDateTime HeapUseBy3rdPartyLibBugFix:HeapUseBy3rdPartyLibBugFix M_Bitworks20161226CLOSED:M_Bitworks20161226CLOSED Orig_Port_to_Vx7_Review_changes_by_jdn:Orig_Port_to_Vx7_Review_changes_by_jdn ReSquashM_BitworksIntoMaster:ReSquashM_BitworksIntoMaster master:master
Pushing to //bw1/Public/Bitworks/Projects/Alcatraz/Vehicle.git
To //bw1/Public/Bitworks/Projects/Alcatraz/Vehicle.git
 = [up to date]      FixSetOsDateTime -> FixSetOsDateTime
 = [up to date]      HeapUseBy3rdPartyLibBugFix -> HeapUseBy3rdPartyLibBugFix
 = [up to date]      Orig_Port_to_Vx7_Review_changes_by_jdn -> Orig_Port_to_Vx7_Review_changes_by_jdn
 = [up to date]      master -> master
 * [new branch]      M_Bitworks20161226CLOSED -> M_Bitworks20161226CLOSED
 * [new branch]      ReSquashM_BitworksIntoMaster -> ReSquashM_BitworksIntoMaster
 ! [rejected]        BitworksDevelopment -> BitworksDevelopment (non-fast-forward)
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/AlcatrazVehicleBW1/FixSetOsDateTime'
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/AlcatrazVehicleBW1/HeapUseBy3rdPartyLibBugFix'
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/AlcatrazVehicleBW1/Orig_Port_to_Vx7_Review_changes_by_jdn'
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/AlcatrazVehicleBW1/master'
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/AlcatrazVehicleBW1/M_Bitworks20161226CLOSED'
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/AlcatrazVehicleBW1/ReSquashM_BitworksIntoMaster'
error: failed to push some refs to '//bw1/Public/Bitworks/Projects/Alcatraz/Vehicle.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

The branch it is rejecting **BitworksDevelopment** was moved in the local repository to point to the head of the master branch in an attempt to discard the old **BitworksDevelopment** branch which was squash merged into master.  The intent was to start new development branching off of the current master head. My understanding was that the push would overwrite the tracking branch pointer on the remote AlcatrazVehicleBW1 bare repository.  It appears there is yet again a Git concept I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The branch it is rejecting **BitworksDevelopment** was moved in the local repository to point to the head of the master branch in an attempt to discard the old BitworksDevelopment branch which was squash merged into master.

Well, that's the problem, then.  Note that the easiest thing here would be simply to *delete* this branch name.

> ... because my local repository is **behind** the remote repository

That's the *complaint* from Git, but the complaint is ... well, "wrong" is the wrong word; maybe a better word is "presumptive".

Remember that in Git, branch *names* merely point to *one particular commit*.  That commit is the "tip of the branch":

```
...--A--B         <-- br1
         \
          C--D--E   <-- br2
                 \
                  F   <-- br3
```

Here, commits `A` and `B` are on *all three branches*, with branch name `br1` pointing to `B`, so that `B` is the *tip commit* on `br1`.  Commits `C` through `E` are on two branches, with `E` being the tip of `br2`, and `F` is only on one branch, and is the tip of `br3`.

Git allows you to add new branch name labels, to jump existing labels around arbitrarily, and to delete branch name labels entirely.  However, there's a "normal pattern" for name movement, and that's in a "forward-only" direction.  Even without adding any new commits, I can move `br1` forward, to any of `C` through `F`, and Git will believe that this is normal and just do it.  I can move `br2` forward to `F`.  I can't move `br3` forward as there are no commits beyond `F`.

Suppose, though, I add a new commit `G`:

```
...--A--B----------G   <-- br1
         \
          C--D--E   <-- br2
                 \
                  F   <-- br3
```

Since `G`'s parent is `B`, I can move `br1` forward to point to `G`.  `G` points back to `B`, just as `C` points back to `B`, so moving `br1` to either `C` *or* `G` is OK.

Once I do this move, though, Git resists having `br1` move *back* in any way.

Suppose that I copy `G` to a new commit `G'` that I tack onto the end of `F`:

```
...--A--B----------G   <-- br1
         \
          C--D--E   <-- br2
                 \
                  F   <-- br3
                   \
                    G'
```

If I now ask Git to move `br1` to point to `G'`, what happens to `G`?

With nothing pointing to `G`, we'll "lose" it.  Git won't be able to find it, and if I did not save its hash somewhere (in my reflogs, or on my screen), so will I.<sup>1</sup>  Hence, a request to move `br1` from `G` to `G'` is a *non-fast-forward*.<sup>2</sup>

The basic assumption here is that when you are pushing to a bare repository, if your requested branch label change is not a "fast forward", you probably weren't aware that commit `G` even *exists* on the bare repository, as it was probably sent there by someone else, working in parallel, who merely beat you to the `git push` step.  In this case, you need to `git fetch` from the bare repository to *pick up* commit `G`, then figure out how to get your own work to *append* to the existing commits, rather than removing `G`.  (That would usually be by rebasing or merging.)

To tell a Git server that it should move a branch, even though the motion will lose some commits, you must apply one of the various "force" flags.  The easy one to apply is `--force` or `-f`, which just tells the server: "I know what I'm doing, lose some commits already."  The slightly longer one, which is safer, is `--force-with-lease`: you have your Git tell their Git "I believe the branch points to commit `G`, and if so, make it point to `G'` instead."

The basic assumption is wrong, and `G` *is* your commit.  You do know it's there, and you are intending to remove it.  So, since your Git knows about it, you can use `--force-with-lease` to check that their (the bare repo's) `BitworksDevelopment` still points to the same commit, and if so, override it with your new replacement.  Or, if you know you're the only one doing things to the bare repository, you can just use plain old `--force`.

Of course, as in footnote 2, it's actually simpler to just delete the name entirely, as is the more typical pattern with squash-merge.  In this case, since the graph looks more like this:

```
...--A--B--C   <-- master
         \
          ... [the old BitworksDevelopment]
```

the commits you will be losing by just deleting the branch name are the ones you've squash-merged in as commit `C`.  The name `master` suffices to hold commit `C`; you don't need *two* names for it.  At least, not yet: you *will* want another name for `C` as soon as you go to make new commits that will come after `C`, but that you don't want to find via the name `master`.

Note that Git's protectiveness in bare repositories applies only to non-fast-forward branch name updates.  Deleting a branch, losing the commits, is perfectly fine!  You do have to use `git push --delete origin BitworksDevelopment` to send the delete-request to the server, though, so it's not like this will happen by accident.  This is quite different from normal development pushes, where the race between two developers, both pushing to the same branch, resulting in non-fast-forwards, *is* a normal, everyday accident, that deserves protecting-against.

---

<sup>1</sup>Bare repositories generally don't have reflogs, and do run a garbage-collect right after pushes, so `G` might get really-removed pretty quickly.

<sup>2</sup>The technical definition of a fast-forward branch-name move is that the commit to which the name *currently* points is an ancestor of the commit to which you propose to point it.  Since regular merge commits point back to two or more commits, moving a branch name to a new merge commit that simply combines that branch with another branch, is a fast-forward.  The same is true for most squash "merges" as well: we add onto the main branch a single commit that represents all the work done in several commits on the other branch (and then we discard that other branch entirely).  The difference in your case is that you're deliberately doing this *without* discarding the other branch; instead, you're trying to *alter* the other branch, in a non-fast-forward manner.

Comment: I ended up moving my **BitworksDevelopment** branch back to where it was (old development) and then deleting it.  Then I opened the AlcatrazVehicleBW1 bare repository and deleted the tracking branch **BitworksDevelopment** there also.  Next I need to delete it from the 3rd repository located on GitLab server which is shared with team members.  So to delete **BitworksDevelopment** branch on GitLab (which is my origin) I would use:  `git push --delete origin BitworksDevelopment`.  Correct?

Comment: Once I have fully deleted BitworksDevelopment could I then re-create it at the squash-merged location and begin a new set of development?  Or should I keep coming up with new names for my development branch?

Comment: Would another alternative have been to break the tracking link before moving my **BitworksDevelopment** branch using the command `git branch --unset-upstream BitworksDevelopment` before trying to move it and push it to bare repository?

Comment: The trick to all of these is realizing that there are many clones of the repository. Each clone has its own names for branches and remote-tracking branches, but they *default* to copying the "upstream" name to a remote-tracking branch, so they will likely all have `origin/BitworksDevelopment`. When updating a remote-tracking branch, your (and their) Git will behave like a forced push: just take their word for it. The only problem comes in if someone made their own *local* branch using (and thus relying on) the name `BitworksDevelopment` and/or `origin/BitworksDevelopment`. [cont'd]

Comment: You can therefore "safely" re-use a branch name when either: no one else is using it, or: everyone who *is* using it, understands about (and is ready to deal with) sudden changes to the `origin/name` version. Otherwise it's generally good to invent new branch names, but obviously at some point all the good ones are taken. :-) If you delete, wait a decent interval, then re-use, that gives everyone else time to figure out things on their end.

Comment: So, answer to first comment: yes, correct. Second comment: yes, but might be wise to come up with new names. Third comment: the "upstream" linkage is there for your convenience. The bare repository doesn't know you're "downstream", it just gets push requests of the form: "here are some commits, and now I'd like to ask you to change your branch names to point to these specified commits."

Comment: (BTW, I just noticed that the word "they" / "their" is ambiguous above: every fetch or push is pairwise, with two Gits and two repositories, and usually "they" is the other repo. But above I mentioned other users' clones; I meant that when "they"—let's say, user U—fetches from bare-repo B, user U will just take B's word for it that U's `origin/BitworksDevelopment` should now point to commit `1234567...`. It's the push direction, from user to bare-repo, that checks for fast-forward-ness.)